# Delete File in SharePoint folder using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint ExcelService to manipulate an excel file and then save it to the Shared Documents folder using

```
ExcelService.SaveWorkbookCopy()
```

Now I want to delete those files I saved earlier. What is the best way to achieve this using C# in a Asp.Net MVC Application?

I tried it using the REST Service, but I could not really find any tutorials and as the code is now, I get a WebException "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
I tried two versions for my REST URL, neither worked.

```
var fileSavePath = "http://sharepointserver/Collaboration/workrooms/MyWebSiteName/Shared%20Documents/";
var excelRestPath_1 = "http://sharepointserver/Collaboration/workrooms/MyWebSiteName/_api/web/";
var excelRestPath_2 = "http://sharepointserver/_api/web/";

    public static bool DeleteExcelFromSharepoint(int id, string excelRestPath)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = "/Shared%20Documents/" + id + ".xlsm";
            string url = excelRestPath + "GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + filePath + "')";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "DELETE";
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.IfMatch, "*");
            request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "DELETE");

            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("DELETE failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode));
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomLogger.Error("Error deleting Excel from Sharepoint", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use nuget package `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM`:

```
using (var sp = new ClientContext("webUrl"))
{
    sp.Credentials =  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    sp.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath).DeleteObject();
    sp.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

that will ensure that file is removed - if you want to make sure the file existed during removal:

```
using (var sp = new ClientContext("webUrl"))
{
    sp.Credentials =  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var file = sp.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
    sp.Load(file, f => f.Exists);
    file.DeleteObject();
    sp.ExecuteQuery();
    if (!file.Exists)
        throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that looks great. I tried it an got an UnauthorizedAccessException, although I created those files. Do I have do activate something special on the SharePoint to be able to delete files?

Comment: Using DefaultCredentials usually does not work in this scenario, you might want to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials or  System.Net.NetworkCredential. If you need to pass user authority, use OAuth.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using REST, you can refer to the link
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_File)

My example code is:

```
string resourceUrl = "https://<BaseURL>/sites/<SubSite>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/<SubSite>/Documents/New Folder/xyz.docx')";            

        var wreq = WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        wreq.Headers.Remove("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED");
        wreq.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    wreq.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "DELETE");
        //wreq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        wreq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        wreq.Method = "POST";
        wreq.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
        wreq.Timeout = 1000000;
        wreq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        wreq.ContentLength = 0;
        string result = string.Empty;
        string JsonResult = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
            result = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Good add by specifying that site and subsite has to be added to relativeURL. That took me a bit to find. Here is another link for reference on that: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/642f51a5-73fc-4606-a51f-da6d23c15762/http-400-bad-request-when-using-getfilebyserverrelativeurl-or-getfolderbyserverrelativeurl?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

Having tried the answers above and but still not getting the files deleted I found this and it works perfectly

```
var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(“FullSharePointURIofDocument“);
request.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
request.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential(“SharePointUser“,”SharePointUserPassword“);
request.Method = “DELETE“;
var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

thanks to [BizTalkBox](https://biztalkbox.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/programmatically-upload-and-delete-documents-from-sharepoint-library/)